# custom fields are not showing in order summary when we goto payment page in checkout page magento2

Tags: magento2

I have override the file DefaultConfigProvider.php which in Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function aroundGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $result = $proceed();

    if (isset($result['totalsData'])) {
        $totalsData = $result['totalsData'];

        if (isset($totalsData['items'])) {
            $items = $totalsData['items'];

            foreach ($items as &$item) {
                $item['custom_text'] = $this->getCustomtext($item['item_id']);
                $item['custom_values'] =  $this->getCustomvalues($item['item_id']);
            }

            $result['totalsData']['items']=$items;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Custom values are showing in shipping page when we goto the shipping page it is disappears. please help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To display additional data to checkout summary you will need to override the

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html
```

maybe this [post](https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-checkout-summary-magento-2/) will help you more about how to customize the checkout summary.